# Configuring PuTTY for Windows 8 cmd shell prompt

Tags: windows-8, putty, cmd.exe, console, telnet

Is there some recommended configuration / settings of PuTTY for Telnet connecting on Windows 8 shell/Telnet. I ask this because in default conf of PuTTY cursor behavior is little strange. e.g. with arrow keys I can move around the screen, listing of last commands for arrow up did not work.

Comment: What's the operating system or shell of the server?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Forget Telnet as quickly as possible (it's insecure and the Windows telnet server is no longer supported); and use SSH instead. [Bitvise WinSSHd](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) works correctly with arrow keys and even full-screen console programs.

Comment: that should be a comment, not an answer ;)